# Read an HTML file data to generate a new html File

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to Create a HTML report. In this at run time of execution of my code i create a HTML file which has details of report in table format and some labels.
Now my HTML Report should read the file as in col-row format so that i can traverse to required data and get the same in my HTML Report.

my new Report

```
<tr><td>
<a " href=./" target="_top">All Test</a><br>
<a " href=./" target="_top">All Errors</a><br> ......
</td><td><table>{Here the data should be generated as per click on the above link}</table></td>
```

The data should be generated by reading the HTML file and when in clicks the Link (eg.Alltest)

And i am not getting what to write in front of `href` in the link.

UPDATE: Create a HTML page which is created from data of another HTML file. In other words i want to add a table which create the contents of it dynamically on click event of the link, and the contents are stored in another HTML file.

UPDATE2:
1. On Load ALLTest link will be active and data will be loaded in table from another HTML file.
2. If the user clicks the Allerror Link the rows containing status error in HTML file should be loaded in table.

UPDATE3:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"report.html", success:function(result){
   result=*{updated result}*
   $(".mytable").html(result);
  }});
});});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Consider improving it to provide facts and references to your project or a sample of it. Also, do you want to do this in vanilla JavaScript or you want to use a framework such as jQuery?

Comment: I can use anything which completes the purpose

Comment: Okay! Provide some more details, like where will the data be taken from (the file path), and a full step by step description. What you want to happen when you do what.

Comment: I have updated the question please review it ...

Comment: What clicking "All Test" should be doing? Where should it link to? You didn't explain this very crucial part in your question.

Comment: When replying now to comment please use `@` for example @Shadow to notify who you reply to otherwise people won't see you replied.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: the link goes no where it is to fire the command of javascript and show the required data in Table

Comment: So what's wrong with such inline script? `<a href="#" onclick="DoSomething(); return false;">`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I want the script which will read data from another HTML file and puts it in my table.

Comment: I see.. using jQuery it becomes really simple then, see Prutswonder answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2321/discussion-between-lah2iv-and-shadow-wizard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code sample and the provided tags, I assume you're trying to generate the contents of the `TABLE` tag. To do this, you need to fix the HTML code, because your anchor (`A`) tags do not have a valid `href` attribute:

```
<tr><td>
<a href="#" class="showtests">All Test</a><br>
<a href="#" class="showerrors">All Errors</a><br> ......
</td><td><table class="mytable">{Here the data should be generated as per click on the above link}
</table></td>
```

To make [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) selections a bit easier, I've added some class attributes. Now you can use the following jQuery script:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".showtests").click(function() { 
        $(".mytable").load("http://www.mysite.com/tests.html");
        $(".mytable TD:nth-child(3):not(':contains(\'test\')')").parent().remove();   
    });
    $(".showerrors").click(function() { 
        $(".mytable").load("http://www.mysite.com/errors.html");
        $(".mytable TD:nth-child(3):not(':contains(\'error\')')").parent().remove();   
    });
});
```

After the HTML rows are loaded into the table, the rows not containing the right status ("test" or "error") are removed. This example checks the third column, which you can adjust by updating `nth-child(3)` with the correct column index.

Comment: Thanks for reply in the above code how can i read the data from another html file to put it in `var html`

Comment: For that, you can use the jQuery load method. I've updated the code sample for you.

Comment: Thanks my file contains only <tr> and <td> elements is it ok. and my question was read specific row contents

Comment: I've added a filter for you to exclude rows that have a different status.

Comment: :Hi i tried this `$(".mytable").load("http://www.mysite.com/errors.html");` but it doesn't load anything from my local html file

Comment: The code ` $("TD:nth-child(3):not(':contains(\'error\')')").parent().remove();` also removes the td of oyher tables on page will you suggest me the code for same using `.ajax` and manupulating the data in result.I have updated some steps

Comment: I've updated the sample to prevent the other tables from being affected by the row removal.